# Alternativa a ORDER BY RAND()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc, pdo

alguien me podria ayudar con un metodo mas seguro y exitoso que ORDER BY RAND() para extraer registros aleatorios... tengo que usar dicho query varias veces repetidas al mismo tiempo pero al hacerlo tantas veces se rompe el codigo! GRACIAS`SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;`

Comment: Podrias colocar el codigo que estas utilizando? ademas, que estas consultando? a que te refieres con "romper el codigo" acaso no hace la consulta? y para que necesitas tener registros aleatorios, son cosas que debes plasmar en tu pregunta

Comment: Es una consulta select normal pero bueno lo pondre

Comment: si, pone el codigo, porque order by RAND no hace lo que vos pensas que hace.. no ordena aleatoriamente las filas... si no que le dice que ordene por determinada columna...

Comment: a ver... explica que queres lograr con esto... asi podemos darte alternativas, porque ese codigo NO ORDENA ALEATORIAMENTE NADA....

Comment: Ya es un SELECT * FROM nombretabla ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10; Si esta re mal me doy cuenta porque me rompe todo el codigo pero busco una alternativa o algo que extraiga registros aleatorios

Comment: Solo quiero extraer registros aleatorios de una tabla sin exigir muchos recursos extraer para pintar en pantalla..

Comment: tu idea es obtener registros aleatorios de una tabla.. empieza por poner eso en tu pregunta... cuantos registros tiene tu tabla? no es mas facil hacerlo en php? vas a comerte montones de cosas para hacerlo aleatorio... no es tan simple.. por eso necesitamos saber cantidad de registros...

Comment: Y cada dia tendrian mas ya que seria la base de datos un pseudo diccionario y cada tabla una categoria de palabras, ej, verbos, adjetivos, etc entonces los registros que almacena cada tabla serian muy variado pero miles de seguro

Comment: ¿Dónde te afecta el codigo? espero que no sea por el rand
podrías intentar `SELECT * FROM tabla ORDER BY FIELD(columna,RAND())`

Comment: Bueno lo que pasa es que efectuo ese select a diferentes tablas con orden by rand, y en algun momento parace que se corta o pasa algo que corta y rompe el codigo dejando de efectuarse... pondria todo el codigo pero es mucho

Comment: Y tambien en algun momento devuelve la consulta vacia y eso rompe el codigo pueden ver aqui lo que devuelve https://www.fabricadepoemas.com/poema/adjetivo en un ejemplo esa misma consulta debo efectuarla 4 veces mas con diferentes tablas

Comment: Sinceramente no entiendo que intentas hacer o para que vas a usarlo, asi no se puede ayudar, solo traes datos aleatorios, pero, de que tabla? acaso hay algun dato que conecte con otra? o simplemente es arrojar 1 data de cada tabla

Comment: Ya lo resolvi pueden ver el resultado aca https://www.fabricadepoemas.com se me rompia el codigo por caracteres como ñ o acentos... pero elemine los datos con esos caracteres y anduvo gracias a todos